# Which Java is in use

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to figure out, which java is my firefox using.
I am using Fedora 20 with Firefox 31. I need to get access to an application which is using java.
But i'm so confused, because my friend installed like 10x java version on my PC.
I know, if i type `which java` in the terminal, i got the one. But that's just a simlink. I need to get to the ControlPanel to add some Exceptions for a Site. I found some java versions with a control panel, but i don't think it's the right one, because my exceptions are not working.

Answer (score 4):

To detect the java version used by your browser, you can use Oracle website:

https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp

Comment: @azurefrog Sorry, you are right. I had not realized the language was in the URL. I have already changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can type `about:plugins` in the address bar and search for the Java plugin. You should see the version in the plugin details, under the plugin name.

Alternatively you can click the "Open Menu" icon at the top right and go to `Addons > Plugins`. There you can search for Java. The version should be part of the name.